# python pycurl get final url redirect

Tags: python, pycurl

i need visit website whit pycurl, follow redirects, and print final url, i write this python code :

```
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://localhost/redirect.php')
c.setopt(c.HTTPPOST, values)
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, buf_pagina.write)
c.setopt(c.HEADERFUNCTION, buf_header.write)
c.setopt(c.CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30)
c.setopt(c.AUTOREFERER,1)
c.setopt(c.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
c.setopt(c.COOKIEFILE, '')
c.setopt(c.TIMEOUT, 30)
c.setopt(c.USERAGENT, '')
c.perform()
```

i need print the final url, how can i make this ? thanks.

the solution is this : url_effective  = c.getinfo(c.EFFECTIVE_URL)

Comment: do you really need to use `pycurl`? If not, try using `requests`, the solution to do what you want is, as far as I remember, really more obvious.

Comment: yes, i need use pycurl, is very fast library !

Comment: here's a way that some guy implemented in php: http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/curl-get-final-url-after-inital-url-redirects-544144.html good thing with curl, it's that the library behaves the same across languages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here's an adaptation of the PHP script I linked in the comments:

```
import pycurl
import sys
import StringIO

o = StringIO.StringIO()
h = StringIO.StringIO()

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21444891')
# c.setopt(c.HTTPPOST, values)
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, o.write)
c.setopt(c.HEADERFUNCTION, h.write)
c.setopt(c.CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30)
c.setopt(c.AUTOREFERER,1)
c.setopt(c.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
c.setopt(c.COOKIEFILE, '')
c.setopt(c.TIMEOUT, 30)
c.setopt(c.USERAGENT, '')
c.perform()

h.seek(0)

location = ""

for l in h:
    if "Location" in l:
        location = l.split(": ")[-1]

print location
```

though, as this example shows, you may not always have the full URI, only the path part of the URI (but if that's the case, that's easy to add the fqdn back)